# Создать список функций

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, указатели, функциональное-программирование

1. Помогите сделать список ф-ций.
2. Значения по умолчанию будут ли работать?

И если есть советы как запомнить, буду благодарен)

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    void f0(bool b = true);
    void f1(bool b = true);
    void f2(bool b = true);
    std::list<???> listFunc;    // тут нужна помощь
    //QList<???> listFunc;
}

A::A() {
    listFunc.append(f0);
    listFunc.append(f1);
    listFunc.append(f2);
}

void main() {
    A a;
    a.listFunc.at(1)(false);// или a.listFunc[1](false);
    a.listFunc.at(0)();
}
```

Comment: Это не обычные функции, а методы класса. Для какого объекта вы хотите вызывать эти `f0`, `f1`, `f2`?

Comment: Нестатические функции класса принадлежат экземпляром класса. Они вызываются для обьекта

Comment: для объекта `this`. Более того этот объект будет в единственном экземпляре.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши "функции" - это не просто функции, а методы класса. Из вашего вопроса не ясно, для какого объекта вы собираетесь вызывать эти методы класса.

Например

```
std::list<std::function<void(bool)>> listFunc;
```

и далее

```
listFunc.push_back(std::bind(&A::f0, this, std::placeholders::_1));
listFunc.push_back(std::bind(&A::f1, this, std::placeholders::_1));
listFunc.push_back(std::bind(&A::f2, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

или через лямбды

```
listFunc.push_back([this](bool b) { f0(b); });
listFunc.push_back([this](bool b) { f1(b); });
listFunc.push_back([this](bool b) { f2(b); });
```

Вызов

```
listFunc.front()(false);
```

В таком варианте привязка конкретного объекта (`this`) делается в момент заполнения списка.

---

Можно поступить и по старинке

```
std::list<void (A::*)(bool)> listFunc;
```

далее

```
listFunc.push_back(&A::f0);
listFunc.push_back(&A::f1);
listFunc.push_back(&A::f2);
```

Но вызов тогда будет таким

```
(a.*listFunc.front())(false);
```

В таком варианте указание конкретного объекта (`a`) делается в момент вызова.

---

Применение `std::function` в первом варианте привносит лишние накладные расходы, во многих случаях совершенно не оправданные. Но из-за того, что ни тип `std::bind`, ни тип лямбды в С++ не является однозначно определенным, приходится таки волей-неволей использовать `std::function`. (В этом отношении устаревший `std::bind1st` был лучше.)

Более эффективной альтернативой первому варианту может быть "ручная" реализация

```
struct Af
{
  A *self;
  void (A::*f)(bool);

  void operator ()(bool b) const
    { (self->*f)(b); }
};
```

и далее

```
std::list<Af> listFunc;
...
listFunc.push_back({ this, &A::f0 });
listFunc.push_back({ this, &A::f1 });
```

и вызов

```
listFunc.front()(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    void f0(bool b = true);
    void f1(bool b = true);
    void f2(bool b = true);
    std::list<void (A::*)(bool)> listFunc;    // ??? ????? ??????
    //QList<???> listFunc;
};

A::A() {
    listFunc.push_back(&A::f0);
    listFunc.push_back(&A::f1);
    listFunc.push_back(&A::f2);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    for(auto f: a.listFunc)
        (a.*f)(false);// ??? a.listFunc[1](false);
}
```

Естественно, что значения по умолчанию работать не будут, потому что их подстановка выполняется во время компиляции; у вас же функции вызываются по адресу, и какая именно функция будет вызвана - компилятор определить не в состоянии.

Comment: Так как добавление происходит в конструкторе класса, можно просто:  listFunc.push_back(f0);...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А точно можно? Гцц считает, что нельзя: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7UQIl8

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не знаю по каой причине какой то компилятор считает, что не может конструктор класса или функция_член работать с функциями этого же класса, без указателей на члены класса.  Один и тот же обьект, одна и та же область видимости.  Мой компилятор это нормально воспринимает, да и читал я об этом давно, не помню в какой, но в книге Страуструпа...  Но, в любом случаи спасибо, я поинтересуюсь, почему где то это может быть ошибкой

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Нашел: [`[expr.unary.op]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4). Тут вроде написано, что гцц прав.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не сошлюсь на стандарт, не настолько хорошо знаю, но когда нужно брать адрес функции-члена, то нужен  таки `&A::f`. VС++ тоже ругается, кстати...

Comment: Интересно, что за компилятор стоит у ARHovsepyan. Я тут попроверял разные на gcc.godbolt, и у меня этот синтаксис сжевал только `icc`, и то с `-fpermissive`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, мне 54 года, и  я  в 51 от английского языка знал только буквы, а в программировании только о битовых операциях.. Трудно и работать и  заняться семейными делами, общаться с внуками, детьми и другими людьми, самостоятельно изучать программирование и к тому же  выучить хорошо английский язык. Так что я не могу понять что там написано, но  спасибо...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, MinGW 5.3 32bit

Comment: @Harry, ну и почему мой компилятор не ругается, если стандарт этого требует?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan GCC вообще имеет привычку с настроками по умолчанию игнорировать многие отхождения от стандарта. Те же массивы неконстантной длины, например. Попробуйте с `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`. На счет ссылки - вот, перевел на скорую руку... https://pastebin.com/BKMSNzEP

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду, спаибо

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Какой именно компилятор? Все ли предупреждения в нем включены? Опции на соответствие стандарту?

Comment: Да, все там включено

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да, но компилятор вы не указали :)

Comment: выше в комментариях

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А, да, не заметил. Ключ `-pedantic` (или как-то так, словом, строгое соответствие стандарту - с GCC не работаю, не уверен, как правильно) не пробовали?